# A set of one tuple in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, set, tuples

Experimentally, I was able to create one like this:

```
s = set(((1,2),))
>>> s
{(1, 2)}
>>> (1, 2) in s
True
```

but the syntax looks a bit overloaded. Can someone please explain why it has to be this way to work (three sets of parentheses and a comma)?

Comment: You could also use `set([(1, 2)])`, that might be visually easier to parse

Comment: Can also drop `set()` and use `{(1, 2)}`

Comment: you could have also use `{(1, 2)}` which is more clear. You instead used the constructor `set` which requires an iterable of items, and you decided to use *another* tuple as that iterable, and singleton tuples always look weird (and don't make much sense). so, you could have used a list, `set([(1,2)])`

Comment: To create a tuple of one element you the extra comma at the end, if there's not comma, it could be a math expression. More info https://wiki.python.org/moin/TupleSyntax

Comment: You can use S={(1, 2)} which is more elegant

Comment: Thanks! {(1, 2)} apparently is the way to go. Just wondering how exactly the construct in the question works.

Comment: Is because the `set` constructor takes an iterable (thus you use 3 sets of parentheses). You could also do `s = set()` and `s.add((1, 2))`.

Comment: you can also create it like this `s={((1,2),)}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have used `set([(1, 2)])` to achieve the same.

You have one set (no, no pun intended...) of parentheses for the function call. `set()` takes an iterable as argument, the list that contains your only tuple.

If you want to use a tuple instead of a list, it gets a bit harder to read. The tuple equivalent of the list `[item]` is the tuple `(item,)` - the comma makes it a tuple, not the parentheses.

So, replacing my `[ (1, 2) ]` with `( (1, 2), )`, you get your `set(((1, 2),))`

And, of course, as noted in the comments, `{(1, 2)}` would be the easiest way to write it...

Answer (score 0):

The trailing `,` simply tells python that the value is a sequence, a `tuple` in this case.

Parentheses are normally used in mathematical expressions. And they are also used to define tuples.

```
>>> (3 + 2)
5
>>> (10)
10
```

If there is only one element inside a pair of parentheses, it is considered as an expression and is evaluated, returning a single value.

In order to tell python explicitly that it's a `tuple`, a `,` has to be added at the end.

```
>>> (10,)
(10,)
>>> t = 1,
>>> t
(1,)
>>> type(t)
<class 'tuple'>
```

Coming to your question,

```
s = set(((1,2),))
```

`(1, 2)` is a `tuple`.
`((1, 2),)` is a `tuple` of tuples (having only one tuple in this case).
Something similar to this,

```
>>> ((1, 2), (3, 4))
((1, 2), (3, 4))
```

with only the first element.

Converting `((1,2),)` to a `set` will return a `set` with `(1, 2)` as the only element. The outermost pair of parentheses is simply the `set` function call.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, you want to validate that the tuple `(1, 2)` is in `s`? Taking advantage of python's flexibility for readability might help you understand why the number of parentheses is necessary.

```
set( # first paren is for calling the function set
    ( # second paren creates the object of items set should look at
        (1,2), # is an item in the set 
    )
    )

# output same as
set(((1,2), (1,2), (1,2)))

# output same as
t = ((1,2), (1,2), (1,2))
set(t)

# output same as
t = (1,2)
t = (t, t, t)
set(t)

# output same as
t = (1, 2)
set([t]*5)
```

`set()` looks for all items in `self`. If you are hoping for a more readable solution than set variables.